# Extract/Trim part of string, Java

Tags: java, trim

Say String x = MynameisMary;

I want String Y to be "Mary"

How do i remove the first 8 characters to make Y equal to Mary??

Comment: use a combination of substring and indexOf

Comment: `String y = "Mary"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) method:

```
String result = x.substring(8);
```